# Object storage for exact-width integer types

Tags: c, standards-compliance, stdint

Are implementations allowed to use more than `N` bits as object storage for `intN_t` and `uintN_t` types, provided the values stored in them fit the required range?

For example, consider a CPU which uses 9-bit bytes. An implementation written for this CPU may have something like `typedef __uint8_as_9 uint8_t`, assuming `__uint8_as_9` refers to a compiler keyword indicating a 9-bit unsigned integer which represents an 8-bit unsigned integer. When the compiler generates code for converting an `unsigned int` to this type, it may (implicitly) truncate the number to 9 bits, then mask out the highest bit. Is this still considered a conforming definition of `uint8_t`, seeing as the compiler ensures the 9-bit value is in the range `0` to `UINT8_MAX`?

Quoting the C standard §7.20.1.1/3, with regards to exact-width integer types (emphasis mine):

> These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with
>   widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, **no padding bits**, and (for the signed types) that have a
>   two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

Since the underlying storage for `uint8_t` actually consists of 9 bits, is this most-significant bit considered a padding bit? Even if it's completely transparent to any (conforming) programs using this implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A compiler for a system with 9-bit bytes (i.e, `CHAR_BIT==9` simply will not define `uint8_t` or `int8_t`. If it did, that 9th bit would be a *padding bit*, which would violate the standard's requirement.

The types are optional and are not provided by implementations that are not able to meet all their requirements.

Such an implementation will still provide `[u]int_least8_t` and `[u]int_fast8_t`, and a program can check whether the macro `UINT8_MAX` is defined to determine whether it can use `uint8_t`.

Comment: Does `CHAR_BIT` include padding bits? If so, it can't have any as the standard says "the values of type `unsigned char` range from `0` to `2^CHAR_BIT - 1`"

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Type `unsigned char` cannot have padding bits, correct. A hypothetical `__uint8_as_9` type that the OP suggests would have one padding bit; it might be legal as an *extended integer type* (see N1570 6.2.5p4 and p6).